# How to influence foreign CSS classes when just using styled components

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components, react-table

I am using `react-table` and I would like to apply CSS rules to the class `rt-td` which is not accessible nor modifiable through what their API offers.

In CSS I would just overwrite the CSS class from within my stylesheet. But how do you that with styled components? I heard it's an anti pattern, but what else should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the parent of the the component `ReactTable` exported by `react-table` is a simple `div`.

```js
const Test = () => (
  <div>
    <ReactTable someProperty={someValue}/>
  </div>
)
```

you can influence the style of the class `rt-td` inside `ReactTable` by 1) converting the parent of `ReactTable` into a `styled-components` and 2) injecting style to override `rt-td` into the CSS of the aforementioned parent.

```js
const Parent = styled.div`
  .rt-td {
    /* your custom style goes here*/
  }
`
const Test = () => (
  <Parent>
    <ReactTable someProperty={someValue}/>
  </Parent>
)
```

Usually that does the trick. If the style definition for `rt-td` inside `react-table` still overrides your custom definition due to specificity, keep repeating the class name `rt-td` inside `Parent` (like this `.rt-td.rt-td`) until your custom style wins.